# Not able to get SOAP response using HttpClient, but works in SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get response of one wsdl. It runs perfectly in SOAP UI. I'm using Httpclient way to get response. The error which I get is

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns22="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Code><soapenv:Value>axis2ns22:Client</soapenv:Value></soapenv:Code><soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is  and the WSA Action = null</soapenv:Text></soapenv:Reason><soapenv:Detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm not able to understand what exactly it is.. I have tried giving text/xml as content-type, then it says version mismatch. I have given as application/soap+xml which worked for couple of other webservices of same wsdl.

Java code

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(HttpClientRequest.getServerUrl());

    if(HttpClientRequest.getHttpRequestHeaderMap() != null) {
        final RequestEntity entity = new ByteArrayRequestEntity(HttpClientRequest.getRequestBodyAsBytes());
        method.setRequestEntity(entity);
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : HttpClientRequest.getHttpRequestHeaderMap().entrySet()) {
            method.addRequestHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }     

   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : HttpClientRequest.getHttpPostParameters().entrySet()) {
        method.addParameter(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    } 

    try {
        httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(Integer.parseInt(Util.getConfig("httpPost.connectionTimeout")));
        httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(Integer.parseInt(Util.getConfig("httpPost.socketTimeout")));
        int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
        String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        HttpClientResponse.setResponseHeaders(method.getResponseHeaders());
        HttpClientResponse.setResponse(response);
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @Saurabh You mean XML request object?

Comment: java code to consume the service

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using axis, it could be a missing SOAPAction header.
At least when i worked with it (which was a while a go) I was instructed to include such a header.

Comment: Can you tell me what should I add?

Answer (score 0):

You code looks a bit complicated. Following is what worked for us:

```
RequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity("SOAP_MSG", "text/xml", "UTF-8");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(entity);
postMethod.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "ACTION_URL");
//Create httpclient instance
httpclient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

where `SOAP_MSG` is actual SOAP Request XML as string. Check your WSDL for `ACTION_URL`